# Debug point not hitting in the RestController in Spring boot Test

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am new to Spring boot I created a Hello World REST API using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.3 (Ultimate Edition) + maven and an integration test to hit the hello end point. The test passes correctly but the debugging does not hit the hello end point in the Rest-controller. I do not want to mock anything. I start the debugging from the test itself. why is the debug point in the hello() method not hitting, even though it gives correct return value. Does it have to do with any debugger setting ? I have uploaded the full project on github here

https://github.com/codecompilelink/HelloWorld.git

```
package example.com.helloworld;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController

public class IAmController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello()
    {
       System.out.println("Hello there...hello I got hit but not in the debugger");
       return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

The test class looks like this

```
package example.com.helloworld;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;


@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class HttpResponseTest {
    @LocalServerPort
    int port;
    private static RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @BeforeAll
    public static void init() {
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldPassIfStringMatches()
    {
        String result = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:"+port+"/hello",String.class);
        assertEquals("Hello World", result);
    }
}
```

**Update:**
I was able to get this sorted by using eclipse IDE, the break point in the controller hits on a different thread than the one running the test. Eclipse did this well, The IntelliJ version mentioned above that I am using will not hit the break point in controller hello() method when I step-over in the test method from the line below to next, and fills the result variable (skipping the hello() method break point)

```
     restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:"+port+"/hello",String.class);
```

If I do not step over and instead press Go then it hits the break point in hello() in controller. So in my opinion this is some bug in the intelliJ my OS is 22.04 Ubuntu LTS

Comment: The issue is not reproducible in IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.3 using the code you provided. Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and specify your IntelliJ IDEA version. Specify you are using Gradle or Maven for the project. I tested with the Gradle project [with](https://i.imgur.com/QFGqSaF.png) and [without](https://i.imgur.com/epfNWNx.png) [delegation](https://i.imgur.com/eP14eaa.png). Sample project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/sf5pdy3dsttn37w/boot-test-sample.zip.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I used maven instead of gradle, have uploaded full project here https://github.com/codecompilelink/HelloWorld.git

Comment: For your Maven linked project, it also [works just fine](https://i.imgur.com/gmFWnly.png). Make sure to [Debug the test configuration](https://i.imgur.com/uHD5kpP.png) (via JUnit). Not the Spring Boot configuration. Also don't forget to place the breakpoint in the controller.

Comment: Yes I am debugging exactly like the screen shot you shared. The project you shared gives me the same problem, my version of IdealJ is an evaluation copy could that be a reason, perhaps?

Comment: No, the evaluation version is fully functional. Do you use 2022.3.3 release? Does the issue occur with the default settings? File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings...: https://i.imgur.com/kbrkC7w.png? Do you have a breakpoint set as shown on my screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely caused by [this IntelliJ IDEA bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-311166/Breakpoint-not-hit-again-after-Step-Over-in-a-Spring-Boot-app).